# C# multi threading with DLL (reflection)

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, thread-safety

I need to organise some lock when several threads get access to common resource at next code architecture:

*There is one dll what has methods (marked with some attribute) which are called by reflection by external program. All this methods are called simultaneously by several threads from that external program.
Inside this methods we have references to other methods what are located in another dll. Inside that another we have methods from other dll.
External run program - (reflection) > dll -> dll -> dll*

Everything was ok till the moment when all threads started go use the same resource (access to email box) at the last dll in a chain. 
One try to delete message but another has already deleted it etc. In fact I do not care about it and can put try/catch if message does not exists but I do not want to use this solution.

I'm thinking about add some lock to read and delete operation and make this delete async way (I do not care about result and do not need to wait till it will be finished - just cleaning old messages) and use some code like below

```
lock(someObject)
{
    //Access to email and delete old messages
}
```

But someObject has to be declared at the top level of that architecture (External run program) and this parameter has to be passed thought all chain. A lot of work and I do not want to do it.

Also I can put this lock at top program what run dll methods but a lot of changes need to be done too because I'll loose a lot of time because I ned to lock small part only but not all.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

An architectural suggestion would be creating a queue of operation accessing the mail resource, to avoid locking. This will loose a feedback for the caller, but it can be done asynchronously if needed. May be just the deleting phase has to be done enqueued, this depend on the exact job you are trying to do. Of course such a queue must be threaed safe, and depending on the level of reliability you want, can be a persistent queue ( like MSMQ )

Answer (score 1):

I do think that the try catch solution you suggested is fine as long as there is no dependency  with regard to order between threads (one thread creating a message, another thread adding an attachment to it). In that case the Queue as mentioned by Felice Pollano might be a good solution.

In the end, whether you lock or not, you'll need to handle conflicts. If these conflicts are predictable you could use locking otherwise try catch might be just fine.